# What's the best way to synchronize users and logins after a load?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have production and a development environment servers.
Once a month I want to dump databases from production and load them into development!

But there's also some users and logins problems (missing logins, permissions, whatever).

What's the best way to synchronize users and logins after a dump?

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more?  Where are there missing logins and permissions?  What is the cause of this?

Comment: The users and logins are not synced between environments. And for the same users/logins its ids are different. So when I put a database from prod in dev (I don't pass master database), I usually have some problem with permissions and users missing, etc.

Comment: If the users/logins are not integrally connected to the data, then just don't import the user table(s).

If the users *are* integrally connected to the rest of the data, then I don't see how you can dump the production database to your development version without also using the production list of users.

Comment: I may import users as well if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **bcp** out your syslogins table from prod master, and **bcp** that table into your dev master.  This has to be done carefully the first time.  I would recommend you drop all user logins (non system default logins) from the dev system.

To **bcp** into master, you will have to set the following flag to allow updates to system tables:

```
sp_configure 'allow updates', 1
```

Then **bcp** in the data to the dev system using a block size of 1, which will allow duplicate rows to be thrown out, without affecting the non-duplicate rows.

```
bcp master..syslogins in prodsyslogins.file -Usa -Psa_password -Smyserver -n{-c} -b1
```

Once your bcp is done, you will want to unset the system table update flag.

```
sp_configure 'allow updates',0
```

If done correctly all your syslogin suids should match up with your sysusers suids in each database, which should resolve the permission issues you were running into.

**EXERCISE CAUTION**  Make sure you have backups of master before your start messing with it.

Comment: i usually delete the probe and sa login from bcp file before bcp in the data again. Also i syncronize the master..sysloginroles table. Another important point: make sure the suid's are getting adjusted in every database after you have loaded the tables.

Comment: But what about all the permissions and grants associated to the users/logins?

Comment: Those permissions are kept in the databases, so they should transfer with the dump.

Answer (score 1):

you can bcp out sysusers,sysalternates and sysprotects before starting the load. Once the db is online, enable 'allow update', delete sysusers,sysalternates and sysprotects and bcp in.

You can also check if there are any suid mismatch.

select t1.suid, t2.suid from sysusers t1, master..syslogins t2 where t1.name = t2.name and t1.suid != t2.suid and t1.suid != -2

Comment: I only need sysusers, sysalternates and sysprotects?

Comment: I think this needs to be clarified. You need to bcp out sysusers, sysalternates, and sysprotects from the DEV server before you start the load. If your accounts don't already match, then you may need to look at my answer.